# Python package, "Updating the INI File"

Tags: python, package, ini

I am working with a python package that I installed called ***bacpypes*** for communicating with building automation equipment, right in the very beginning going thru the pip install & git clone of the repository; the [readthedocs](https://bacpypes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted/gettingstarted001.html) calls out to:

***Updating the INI File
Now that you know what these values are going to be, you can configure the BACnet portion of your workstation. Change into the samples directory that you checked out earlier, make a copy of the sample configuration file, and edit it for your site:***

```
$ cd bacpypes/samples
$ cp BACpypes~.ini BACpypes.ini
```

The problem that I have (is not enough knowledge) is there isn't a sample configuration file that I can see in `bacpypes/samples` directory. Its only a .py files nothing with an .ini extension or name of `BACpypes.ini`

If I open up the samples directory in terminal and run `cp BACpypes~.ini BACpypes.ini` I get an error `cp: cannot stat 'BACpypes~.ini': No such file or directory`

Any tips help thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sample .ini in the documentation, a couple of paragraphs after the commands you copied. It looks like this

```
[BACpypes]
objectName: Betelgeuse
address: 192.168.1.2/24
objectIdentifier: 599
maxApduLengthAccepted: 1024
segmentationSupported: segmentedBoth
maxSegmentsAccepted: 1024
vendorIdentifier: 15
foreignPort: 0
foreignBBMD: 128.253.109.254
foreignTTL: 30
```

I'm not sure why you couldn't copy BACpypes~.ini. I know tilda could be expanded by your shell so you could try to escape it with

```
cp BACpypes\~.ini BACpypes.ini
```

Though I assume it isn't needed now that you have a default configuration file.

Comment: I copied `cp BACpypes\~.ini BACpypes.ini` that you listed above and in terminal on the `bacpypes/samples` directory I tried to run it but I get the same error. I also noticed that table/sample .ini too further down, but I don't understand how to create the `.ini` with that info. Can you give me a tip on creating it with what you have above of the sample .ini? Thank you for your help..

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you're having troubles physically creating the file.
It sounds like you're on a Linux machine. Try to create it with vi, so `vi BACpypes.ini` then enter input mode by pressing `i`, pasting the content of the .ini file and then "save and exit" by pressing Escape then `:wq`.